# Focus event for when element has parent with a class of x

Tags: jquery

When you focus on any element on the page I need an event to fire if the element is within a div with a certain class. The following always returns no:

```
$('body').focusin(function () {
  if ($(':focus').parents('.my-class').length) {
    console.log('yes');
  } else {
    console.log('no');
  }
});
```

When I add the following within the function I can see the first focused element is always logged. It doesnt update as the focus moves to a new element.

```
var focus = $(':focus');
console.log(focus);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
$('input, a').on('focus',function(e){
  if($(this).parents('.my-class').hasClass('my-class')){
    console.log('should fire');
  }
});
```

Here is a working Jsbin

https://jsbin.com/dovivonizo/edit?html,js,console,output

Basically you need to listen for when any input gets focused, and then check it's parent element that is a `div` and see if it has a class of `my-class` or whatever class you want to check for.

You still need to return true so that's why you still need the `.hasClass()` on the end to return true.

Comment: The focused element isnt a direct descender of the class. Also links are focusable not just inputs.

Comment: Not sure how people will focus a link unless they tab to it which most people don't do but I added a link to the input focus listener. I also changed so you can go up to the parent that has the class of `my-class` .

Comment: I think this will be worse for performance than just having a listener on the body and then checking which element had focus when it bubbles up.

Comment: Also I dont think the e is required.

Answer (score 0):

Just binding `focusin` to the intended `div` should work as described in https://api.jquery.com/focusin/

```
    $('div.my-class').focusin(function() {
        //do your stuff
    });
```

In case it's a dynamically added `div` you can use event delegation using `on`

```
    $(document.body).on('focusin', 'div.my-class', function() {
        //do your stuff
    });
```

Comment: I need an event for when you focus on something that isnt in the div.